# Safari: Dragging element is picking up text of overlapping elements

Tags: css, safari

I have an issue in Safari where dragging an element is picking up text in any element overlapping it:

[image: gif showing issue]

Same code works correctly in Chrome and Firefox, using a `transform: translate(0, 0)` workaround. In my testing so far, this happens regardless of styles, so it doesn't seem related to the header being `position: sticky` in this example.

```css
body {
  font-family: system, -apple-system, -webkit-system-font, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0 2rem 0.125rem 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}

.header-wrapper {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}

.page-content {
  padding: 0 2rem;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

div[draggable='true'], .drag-element {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  background-color: slateblue;
  color: white;
  cursor: grab;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  /*
  - removes square corners while dragging and prevents Chrome/Firefox picking up obscuring element,
  but Safari still picks up text of any block-level overlapping element.
  - does not pick up inline els.
  - same if header is block/fixed
  */
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

div[draggable='true']:-webkit-drag {
  background-color: rgb(128, 116, 203);
}

.spacer {
  height: 20rem;
  width: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky-header">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <h3>header</h3>
    <div>div here</div>
    <p>p here</p>
    <span>span here</span>
    <button>button here</button>
    <input type="text" placeholder="text goes here" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page-content">
  <div draggable="true">I'm draggable</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="drag-element">I'm not</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div draggable="true">I'm draggable</div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div draggable="true">I'm draggable</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen of snippet](https://codepen.io/rebolyte/pen/XWYaBQb?editors=1100)

Is this a browser bug or can I work around it somehow?

Comment: Don't have that problem in Chrome, when trying it in the snippet here and in codepen. Might be a browser thing.

Comment: Actually I think it may be the same bug reported in https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=237446

Comment: Hi, I found the same issue. How can you solve it?

Comment: I didn't. Waiting for webkit bug linked above to be fixed